# Parameter mismatch with private parameters in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

TL:DR: getting the error `Supplied parameters do not match any signatures of call target`when trying to use private constructor parameters ie. `constructor (private http: Http) {}`

I'm having some trouble when setting up private parameters in Angular2. I had thought that when a property is declared as private in the constructor, it does not need to be passed in. This seems odd to me and I'm guessing my understanding of this is wrong, but I can't find any information to suggest otherwise. Here's an example of what I mean:

`constructor (private http: Http) {}` from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

The http property is then referred to, however I don't see any Http instance being passed in elsewhere.

I've tried to implement the same thing, however I'm getting the following error:
`Supplied parameters do not match any signatures of call target`, implying, it seems, that an Http instance needs to be passed to the constuctor.

The program is for a 'Gallery' of 'Cards'. The cards are delivered from a 'CardService' which uses Http. This code currently throws an error at the line `mainGallery: Gallery = new Gallery();`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Gallery } from './gallery';
import { CardService } from './card.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ CardService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
    
    mainGallery: Gallery = new Gallery();
}
```

Here is how Gallery looks:

```js
@Component({
    providers: [CardService]
})
export class Gallery{
    cards: Card[] = [];

    constructor(private cardService: CardService){
    }

}
```

I also get the same sort of error if I attempt to use `private http: Http` in the constructor of card service. Any help is much appreciated!

---

EDIT:
Here's my NgModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Did you import HttpModule to your NgModule?

Comment: @MatWaligora thanks, now updated the question to show my NgModule

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Can you give more of a [mcve]? Dependency injection should indeed be at work, but if you try to create a `new` instance yourself you may get problems.

Comment: @MatWaligora this is now added, hopefully it provides the required detail but if you think it'd be better with more/less let me know

Comment: You have to add CardService to providers: [] in Ngmodule :)

Comment: I added it to the providers, but unfortunately I'm still getting the error, it's rather confusing!

Comment: Remove it from the @Component decorator.

Comment: also removed it from the component decorator, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot simply create a `new Gallery()`, you'd have to ask the relevant injector to fetch one for you, since you're not sending the `Gallery`'s constructor function any parameters, this is the injector's job.

Read up here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html